# Bash profile commands with multiple "'` issues

Tags: macos, bash, .bash-profile, bash-alias, macos-sierra

Good day!

I'm currently trying to get the following alias to work. 'git_fetch' and 'git_tree' are custom alias so dont worry about them.

```
alias git_workspace='osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down' -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_fetch\" in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' &> /dev/null && osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down' -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree\" in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' &> /dev/null'
```

(I added linebreaks to increase readability)

```
alias git_workspace='osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' 
-e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" 
to keystroke "n" using command down' -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear 
&& git_fetch\" in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' 
&> /dev/null 
&& osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" 
to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down' 
-e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree\" 
in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' &> /dev/null'
```

However i cant get this to work. Reloading the ~/.profile results in:

```
-bash: alias: application: not found
-bash: alias: Terminal -e tell: not found
-bash: alias: application: not found
-bash: alias: System Events: not found
-bash: alias: to: not found
-bash: alias: tell: not found
-bash: alias: process: not found
-bash: alias: Terminal: not found
-bash: alias: to: not found
-bash: alias: keystroke: not found
-bash: alias: n: not found
-bash: alias: using: not found
-bash: alias: command: not found
-bash: alias: down -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_fetch\" in selected tab of the front window" -e end: not found
-bash: alias: tell &> /dev/null && osascript -e tell: not found
-bash: alias: application: not found
-bash: alias: Terminal -e tell: not found
-bash: alias: application: not found
-bash: alias: System Events: not found
-bash: alias: to: not found
-bash: alias: tell: not found
-bash: alias: process: not found
-bash: alias: Terminal: not found
-bash: alias: to: not found
-bash: alias: keystroke: not found
-bash: alias: n: not found
-bash: alias: using: not found
-bash: alias: command: not found
-bash: alias: down -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree\" in selected tab of the front window" -e end: not found
-bash: alias: tell &> /dev/null: not found
```

Can someone assist me? :)

**EDIT**: I found the solution!

`` alias git_workspace='osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Terminal\" to keystroke \"n\" using command down" -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_fetch\" in selected tab of the front window" -e "end tell" &> /dev/null && osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Terminal\" to keystroke \"n\" using command down" -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree\" in selected tab of the front window" -e "end tell" &> /dev/null' ``

Comment: I found the solution! TY to all that maybe looked into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that the format of alias is something like this:

```
alias thing='commands'
alias thingy="commands"
```

In other words, the commands of the alias must be closed up in quotation marks.

You've got this:

```
alias git_workspace='osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down' -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_fetch\" in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' &> /dev/null && osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down' -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree\" in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' &> /dev/null'
```

Now there's a massive problem that in this excessively long command you have too many quotation marks inbetween. So your alias is really gonna be read like this

```
alias git_workspace='osascript -e '
```

And because you have all these trailing commands after that bit, it breaks your bash_profile file.

The easiest way to circumvent this which I personally always use is to create the script in a separate file, essentially pasting the following into an empty file.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down' -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_fetch\" in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' &> /dev/null && osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down' -e "do script with command \"cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree\" in selected tab of the front window" -e 'end tell' &> /dev/null
```

You can name the file git_workspace.sh or git_workspace or whatever, name is up to you then you need to give the file execution permissions with

```
chmod +x git_workspace.sh
```

After this test the script to make sure it works by running it, like so

```
/path/to/git_workspace.sh
```

And if it executes the way you intended, go to your bash profile file and make this alias

```
alias git_workspace='/path/to/git_workspace.sh'
```

And then it will work. There are of course many many other ways around this, but this is what I find to be simplest, I created a .scripts directory in my home dir and put all the scripts I've created over the years in there. This also makes it easy to backup my scripts in case I want to switch computers or reinstall my OS.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the problem. I managed solving the problem by properly escaping the quotation-marks (with a little of vim-syntax-highlighting) but putting it in another shell-script is the way-to-go i guess.

Answer (score 0):

An alias isn't in the right solution for this - the nested escapes that are required will (have) become unmanageable. I would implement this as a function using a bash capability called a [Heredoc](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings) in a function:

```
git_workspace () {
(
  osascript <<-'EOF'
        tell application "Terminal"' 
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down
        do script with command "cd `pwd`;clear && git_fetch" in selected tab of the front window
        end tell
EOF

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        osascript <<-'EOF'
            tell application "Terminal"
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down
            do script with command "cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree" in selected tab of the front window
            end tell
EOF
   fi
)  &>/dev/null
}
```

- The `osascript` will see the heredoc input as a file rather than a string argument, so the `-e` argument is not required.
- The Heredoc statement will output the text exactly as written between the `<<EOF` and `EOF` markers, with the following caveats:

  - By default a heredoc *will* interpret the \, $, and ` characters. To disable that, enclose the Heredoc `<<EOF` marker in quotes, `<<'EOF'`
  - Everything between the two markers will be output, including leading white space. To allow indenting (the benefit being readable code rather than script capability), bash will strip all leading tabs from the text if the heredoc operator has a dash argument, i.e. `<<-'EOF'`.
  - In every case, the closing heredoc tag must be on a new line with no leading whitespace (tabs or otherwise).

If you use this approach, you can type the osascript commands exactly as they would be issued natively without having to address any issues with bash expansion / replacement.

I wrapped both osascript command sequences in a subshell to make it easier to redirect the output.

If you want to see what the text / argument to osascript look like, modify the function temporarily by replacing `osascript` with `cat` and remove the redirect to /dev/null. As the function is written now, the output looks like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"' 
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down
do script with command "cd `pwd`;clear && git_fetch" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down
do script with command "cd `pwd`;clear && git_tree" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
```

Comment: That's a nice and clean approach i"ll definitely try to use in some other use-cases. TY for the in-depth explanation.